# How can I make a grid like the iOS calendar app?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, grid

Ok, so I am wanting to write a calendar app, but I haven't done much with dates on the iphone and so I'm coming here for some help.

I plan on persisting the data through core data obviously but as far as handling touch events inside of a grid...how would I go about that? Is there some sort of a grid UI element that I am just not seeing in IB? (haha) Once I get my grid setup, I feel like I can handle the rest ok, but I just really don't have any idea where to start on setting up a monthly grid...any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Tapku Library provides an object for a calendar view: http://tapku.com/